# How can I either compile or run a c++ file with two shortcut keys in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It seems that all the extensions in the market place can only compile and run a c++ file at the same time, but I don't want that. I wish to achieve this: When I press some shortcut key, a c++ file will be compiled, but without running it. And when I press another shortcut key, the c++ program will be run, without compiling it. How can I do that?

Comment: don't add a `preLaunchTask` to your launch configuration

Answer (score 0):

Well, problem solved. I deleted `preLaunchTask` in my `launch.json`, and I can use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`B` to compile my file. Then download CodeRunner, and set

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "cpp": "cd $dir && ./$fileNameWithoutExt"
  },
```

and I can run the code with `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`N`. When I want to debug, I press `f5`.